# Where should I put FFMPEG?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, filesystems, download, ffprobe

I have installed ffmpeg and ffprobe, but they just appeared in my downloads folder. I should put them somewhere useful.

I am using macOS Sierra

What is the recommended place to put such downloads? I will then edit my bash $PATH to find them there.

Comment: Are you using them mostly with scripts or manually in the terminal?

Comment: I am only accessing it by a python subprocess command. For now, I have put it in usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 1):

**`/usr/local/bin`** is the standard location for your own binaries. It's in the default macOS PATH, however *after* `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. Binaries placed in `/usr/local/bin` won't override the standard macOS binaries. If you want to use binaries with the same names as default binaries, you should still use this location though and instead edit the PATH to place `/usr/local/bin` before the others.

Comment: There is no need to edit the `PATH`: doing so will not be beneficial because there should never be a `ffmpeg` binary in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, and `ffmpeg` will never be a "standard macOS binary". Putting it in `/usr/local/bin` should be work just fine without messing around with the `PATH`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The question said "such downloads" which I inferred could mean any other binaries too. I've edited my answer to clarify though.

Comment: I inferred the mentioned `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`, but your edit clears up any potential confusion.